# What data structure should I use to model a database/table?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

### Databases usually look like this

```
┃Name|Age|..┃
┠────┼───┼──┨
┃John│025│..┃
┃Carl│033│..┃
┃....│...│..┃
```

In this case I mean a table with a fixed column size and a variable size of unsorted rows which can be addressed by an id.

Is there a data structure in C++11 (or earlier) that can represent data like this?

I thought of a couple of ways of cheating such a structure, but none of them is perfect.

### 1. Separate `std::vector`

```
std::vector<std::string> name;
std::vector<unsigned int> age;

// Write
name.push_back("John");
age.push_back(25);

// Read
std::cout << "The first entry is (" << name[0] << " | " << age[0] << ")\n";
```

Defining a table with many columns takes a lot of markup, though, and writing to it by calling `push_back` on each `std::vector` is really tedeous.

### 2. `std::vector` of `std::tuple`

*(`std::pair` would be enough in this case)*

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, unsigned int>> table;

// Write
table.push_back(std::make_tuple("John", 25));

// Read 1
std::string name;
unsigned int age;
std::tie(name, age) = table[0];
std::cout << "The first entry is (" << name << " | " << age << ")\n";

// Read 2
enum
{
    NAME = 0,
    AGE
}
std::cout << "The first entry is (" << std::get<NAME>(table[0]) << " | "
<< std::get<AGE>(table[0]) << ")\n";
```

*(Sorry, if I messed something up here; I've known about the existence of `std::tuple` since yesterday)*

This is fine, but reading from it takes a lot of markup, this time, when you have to define new variables that you want to put the values in. You could just do the `std::tie` to whatever variable you need the values at, but that becomes unreadable. The second method is almost perfect, but using implicit enums is not something I want to do in C++11.

### 3.  `std::vector` of `std::array`

```
enum
{
    NAME = 0,
    AGE
}

std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2> table;

// Write
table.push_back({"John", "25"});

// Read
std::cout << "The first entry is (" << table[0][NAME] << " | " << table[0][AGE] << ")\n";
```

This is also pretty good, but it suffers the same problem as 2.2 did. Also this only allows `std::string` values. In exchange it offers shorter and nicer syntax, though.

Comment: `std::list<row>` which `row` is a class that represent data that you want to store in each row. Actually it depend on your requirements.

Comment: Most databases use the classical [B-Tree data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)

Comment: Datastructures are tied to algorithms.  Talking about what you are going to *do* to the database is required to determine how you should *store* it.  Even scale matters; a "database" with 10 petabytes of data is going to use a different structure than one with 10 kilobytes.  What operations need to be fast?  Lookup by name?  Lookup by age?  How about joining one table to another by name?  Is threading a concern?  Are the data columns hard typed, or soft typed? How comon are reads and writes?  Etc etc.

Comment: You might be interested in [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/)

Comment: I'd have to load it into memory somehow

Comment: @Yakk But there is no standard container like `vector`, `map`, `list`, `set`, etc. in the STL?

Comment: @kim366 There are many standard containers like `vector` `map` `list` `set` in `std`.  How is that relevant?  I'm saying you aren't stating a problem; saying "like a database" isn't saying anything.  A database is like a database.  Other things are less like a database.  If you want everything a database does, use a database.  If you want something that isn't a database, you **must tell us what it is you want** about the database, and **what about a database you can do without**.  All we have from you is "like a database" with no details about **what that means to you**.

Comment: @kim366 Well you asked what data structure is used by a database, and the answer (or at least one of them) is the B-Tree I mentioned.  Then the next step you could have taken was to search for B-Tree implementations written for C++.

Comment: Okay, I'll clarify: I mean a table with a fixed column size and a variable size of unsorted rows which can be addressed by an id.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is there a standard data structure in C++ that represents a B-Tree?

Comment: What is the ID?  (either examples, or axioms that describe what you need from it)  What is permitted to invalidate the ID? (how long does it remain valid) Is the ID unique, or can duplicates be allowed? (are the duplicates treated like separate entries, or as a list of elements under that ID?) Do you determine the ID when you add things to the table, or is it determined for you, or do you not care? (Like, `auto id = insert_entry( "bob", age(77) );`, or is `"bob"` the ID?)  Can you access the elements without the ID? (Ie, look at all of them?  Must they be in a particular order?)

Comment: There are a whole pile of ways to do this.  Which one is best depends on the above questions, and more.

Comment: Note B-Tree is an implementation detail. A database user doesn't think in terms of B-trees, just like `std::map` user doesn't think in terms of red-black trees. There is a certain API and certain performance guarantees. How you implement that is an entirely separate question.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest a `std::vector<Record>` to hold your records.

Use `std::map<key, vector_index>` as an index into your records.  This will enable you to access records by different search criteria without sorting the vector all the time.

Comment: Why not just `std::map<key, Record>`?

Comment: @kim366:  Your suggestion will make an optimized search for the given key, but it will be slower if a record needs to be found by using a different key.  With the vector, all records are in one place.  One can use multiple maps for different search criteria.  See database theory - index tables.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have't considered is using a `std::vector` of some kind of associative array, be that a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

This would allow you to inspect a given item in the vector (or other sequential container) using the database column names

```
item["Name"]
item["Age"]
```

and so on. You would have to use a variant or something like `boost::any` for the value, obviously.

If you wish to talk to a database in C++, and know at compile time the type the columns have (as you appear to from your suggestions) it might be worth considering ways to generate code with appropriate structures for you directly from the data base scehema. There are a couple of questions around this topic already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304587/hibernate-like-framework-for-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453928/hibernate-like-layer-for-c). What if the db value is null?

Comment: But a `std::map` only allows for two values

Comment: @kim366 those values are the keys used to retrieve the data stored in the data type, which itself may be a type that can contain multiple varieties of data, as doctorlove explains in the answer.

Comment: Map allows *lots* of values, one corrsponding to each key. And a vlaue could be another map - if you use the right type.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is still seeing activity after 5 years, I will answer it myself with the 5 years of programming experience since then.

There is no point in using `std::array` or `std::tuple` to represent a row. A struct is more expressive and has less boilerplate.

The question basically asks the difference between AOS (array of structs), SOA (struct of arrays) and hash maps. The choice between the two depends on what you want to do with the data and how much data there is.

Data is loaded cache lines of 64 bytes with automatic cache preloading when iterating over the data. Since the hash map is non-contiguous and thus cannot take advantage of the caching mechanism, it should only be preferred when individual entries are accessed based on their keys rather than iterating over the entire data set.

The choice between AOS and SOA depends on whether the columns are iterated over individually or together. When iterating separately, by using SOA we can fit more of the same data on the cache line by not looking at the other arrays. For both AOS and SOA, the preferable data structure is `std::vector` which is a simple contiguous data structure and thus the processor has a lot of information for on-the-fly optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

```
#-------------------------------------------
#Try with this piece of code based on <map>
#-------------------------------------------    
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
//---
class myBook
{
public:
    string ISBN;
    string Title;
    int Pages;

    myBook();
    myBook(const myBook &);
    ~myBook(){};
    myBook &operator=(const myBook &pTr);
    int operator==(const myBook &pTr) const;
    int operator<(const myBook &pTr) const;
};

myBook::myBook()
{
    ISBN = "";
    Title = "";
    Pages = 0;
}


myBook::myBook(const myBook &copyin)
{
    ISBN = copyin.ISBN;
    Title = copyin.Title;
    Pages = copyin.Pages;
}


ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const myBook &myBook)
{
    output << myBook.ISBN << ':' << myBook.Title << ':' << myBook.Pages << std::endl;
    return(output);
}


myBook& myBook::operator=(const myBook &pTr)
{
    this->ISBN = pTr.ISBN;
    this->Title = pTr.Title;
    this->Pages = pTr.Pages;
    return(*this);
}


int myBook::operator==(const myBook &pTr) const
{
    if( this->ISBN != pTr.ISBN) return(0);
    if( this->Title != pTr.Title) return(0);
    if( this->Pages != pTr.Pages) return(0);
    return(1);
   }

//---------------------------
main()
{
    map<string, myBook> BooksLibrary;
    myBook book1;
    //---
    book1.ISBN="1243954-23";
    book1.Title="Autobiography by Ben Franklin";
    book1.Pages=432;
    BooksLibrary["0001"] = book1;
    //---
    book1.ISBN="555-USA991";
    book1.Title="I Robot by Isac Asimov";
    book1.Pages=323;
    BooksLibrary["0002"] = book1;
    //---
    for( map<string, myBook>::iterator ii=BooksLibrary.begin();     ii!=BooksLibrary.end(); ii++)
    {
        std::cout << (*ii).first << "|" << (*ii).second << endl;
    }
    //---
    return(0);
}
```