# Data Structure: insert(id,value), delete(id) and getMax()

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I Have to design an *order-book* data structure that allows me to query for the highest **price** of an order which has been inserted and not yet deleted. 
Insert and delete operations are given upfront in a file in which each operation looks like one of the following two:

- TIMESTAMP  **insert**  ID  PRICE
- TIMESTAMP  **delete**  ID

where ID is an integer identifier of a order, timestamp are always in increasing order and each ID appears exactly twice: once in a insert and once in a delete operation, in this order.

From this list of operations, I need to output the time-weighted average of the highest price.

---

As an example, let's say we have the following input:

`10 I 1 10
20 I 2 13
22 I 3 13
24 E 2 
25 E 3 
40 E 1`

We can say that after the `ith` operation, the max is
`10, 13, 13, 13, 10`
and the time-weigthed average is 
`10*(20-10) + 13*(22-20) + 13*(24-22)+13*(25-24)+10*(40-25) =  10.5`
because `10` is the max price between timestamps `[10-20]` and `[25,40]` while 13 in the rest.

I was thinking to use an `unordered_map<ID,price>` and a `multiset<price>` for supporting:

- **insert**  in `O(log(n))`
- **delete** in `O(log(n))`
- **getMax** in `O(1)`

Here is an example of what I come up with:

```
struct order {
  int timestamp, id;
  char type;
  double price;
};

unordered_map<uint, order> M;
multiset<double> maxPrices;
double totaltime = 0;
double avg = 0;
double lastTS = 0;

double getHighest() {
  return !maxPrices.empty() ? *maxPrices.rbegin()
                            : std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}

void update(const uint timestamp) {
  const double timeLeg = timestamp - lastTS;
  totaltime += timeLeg;
  avg += timeLeg * getHighest();
  lastTS = timestamp;
}

void insertOrder(const order& ord) {
  if (!maxPrices.empty()) {
    if (ord.price >= getHighest()) {
      // we have a new maxPrice
      update(ord.timestamp);
    }

  } else  // if there are not orders this is the mex for sure
    lastTS = ord.timestamp;

  M[ord.id] = ord;
  maxPrices.insert(ord.price);
}

void deleteOrder(
    const uint timestamp,
    const uint id_ord) {  // id_ord is assumed to exists in both M and maxPrices
  order ord = M[id_ord];
  if (ord.price >= getHighest()) {
    update(timestamp);
  }
  auto it = maxPrices.find(ord.price);
  maxPrices.erase(it);
  M.erase(id_ord);
}
```

This approach has a complexity of `nlogn` where `n` is the number of active orders.

Is there any faster asymptotic and/or more elegant approach to solving this problem?

Comment: does the algorithm have to be online or offline can work ?

Comment: with some bookkeeping you can get `getMax` in O(1) easily and for inserting and removing elements there are better containers than a `map`

Comment: @marvel308 offline. You have the whole input up front.

Comment: @tobi303 I already have `getMax` with `O(1)`. `map` keep its element sorted, so I can pick the maximum in `O(1)`. Regarding alternatives to `map`, I am having trouble coming up with a better alternative. Can you suggest me something I can take a look at?

Comment: Search the internet for "database normal forms".

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ index table".  I'm sure I already answered similar questions.

Comment: This looks promising: [What data structure should I use to model a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768057/what-data-structure-should-i-use-to-model-a-database-table)

Comment: I was also taking a look at Boost:MultiIndex, which seems a nicer way of doing what I have done manually. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how normal forms can be helpful in lowering the complexity?

Comment: Normal forms will show you how to organize your data and tables for efficient access and reduction of duplicate data.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take the *database* approach.

Place all your records into a `std::vector`.

Create an index table, `std::map</* key type */, size_t>`, which will contain a key value and the index of the record in the vector.  If you want the key sorted in descending order, also supply a comparison functor.

This strategy allows you to create many index tables without having to re-sort all of your data.  The map will give good search times for your keys.  You can also iterate through the map to list all the keys in order.

Note:  with modern computers, you may need a huge amount of data to provide a significant timing improvement between a binary search (map) and an linear search (vector).